# How to rotate gltf model while scrolling the page

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to make the gltf model rotate smoothly while scrolling.
I managed to create a function that converts pageYOffset from pixels to radians

```
let scroollPositionRad = 0;
window.addEventListener("scroll",  onWindowScroll );
function onWindowScroll(){
  let scroollPosition = Math.round(pageYOffset);
  let limit = document.body.offsetHeight - window.innerHeight;  
  scroollPositionRad = (scroollPosition * 2* Math.PI) / limit;
}
```

and a function that rotates and centers the model

```
function centerObj(rad){
  obj.rotation.y = rad;
  let box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject( obj );
  let center = box.getCenter( new THREE.Vector3() );
  obj.position.x += ( obj.position.x - center.x );
  obj.position.y += ( obj.position.y - center.y );
  obj.position.z += ( obj.position.z - center.z );
}
```

if i try to call  centerObj(scrollPositionRad) as animation, gltf model disappears

```
renderer.setAnimationLoop(_ => {
    centerObj(scroollPositionRad);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
})
```

model loading code after scene creation

```
let loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
let obj = null;

loader.load('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aaadraniki/projects/web-pages/assets/models/fender_br/scene.gltf', function(gltf) {
  obj = gltf.scene;
  
  scene.add(obj);

  function centerObj(rad){
    obj.rotation.y = rad;
    let box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject( obj );
        let center = box.getCenter( new THREE.Vector3() );
        obj.position.x += ( obj.position.x - center.x );
        obj.position.y += ( obj.position.y - center.y );
        obj.position.z += ( obj.position.z - center.z );
        }

        centerObj(0.8);

        let scroollPositionRad = 0;
    window.addEventListener("scroll",  onWindowScroll );
    function onWindowScroll(){
        let scroollPosition = Math.round(pageYOffset);
        let limit = document.body.offsetHeight - window.innerHeight;    
        scroollPositionRad = (scroollPosition * 2* Math.PI) / limit;
        }
        
  renderer.setAnimationLoop(_ => {

    centerObj(scroollPositionRad);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
})

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.onscroll = (e) => {
    scene.rotation.y = this.scrollY / 700.0;
  }
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. For instance, why did you choose value 700.0?

Comment: This is the angle of rotation, any value can be written there